# Как организовать хранение картинок и их обработку?

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Есть PHP страничка в виде статьи в которой есть текст и картинки. Эта страничка часто обновляется(изменяется) и естественно что картинки устаривают и начинают плодится, потому что за ними надо следить "вручную" и своевременно удалять. С текстом то все понятно он лежит в базе но как быть с картинками, чтобы не следить за ними и все происходило автоматически. Подскажите как правильно организовать хранение и обработку картинок в моем случае?

Comment: Картинки храните как текст :) https://jsfiddle.net/cbeu1L8c/

Comment: @Visman, красота ) . То есть реально на страничке можно нажать на кнопочку "обзор" выбрать картинку и PHP может конвертнуть в такой формат и положить в базу?

Comment: Пример функции https://truemisha.ru/blog/php/convert-images-to-data-url.html

Comment: @Visman , спасибо вот теперь все ясно. Сначала на файловую систему залить, потом декодировать, потом уже в базу. благодарю.

Comment: Ckeditor, если не ошибаюсь, при отсутствии модуля для загрузки файлов автоматом так перекодирует картинки вставленные с компьютера пользователя при редактировании текста.

Comment: @Visman, вот повезло , именно его я и собрался подключать ) супер!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например

1. Таблица в БД с картинками
2. Таблица со связями картинка-статья
3. Крон-скрипт который ищет картинки, которые не используются в статьях, и удаляет их.